# Adding base64 string to JSON invalidates it

Tags: json, base64

I am creating a JSON Array having a byte64 string data. This is an invalid JSON but when I remove the `displaypic` value by some normal `string` the JSON is valid. Please help me with this. Is there any other way to work with images that has to be parsed on cross platforms. How do I deal with this byte 64 string.

It's a long data so can't add here.. The body limit is 30000. Please see this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u0EX6hiwuYUkLcmxSWqz2mR3nQUq3bBWC04ig1zASfE) for the JSON.

**CODE THAT CREATES JSON**

```
function checkLogin_post()
{
     //$responsedata = array();

    if($this->post('useremail') && $this->post('password'))
    {
        $useremail = $this->post('useremail');
        $password = $this->post('password');


            $this->load->model('loginmodel');

            $table_data = $this->loginmodel->checkLogin($useremail);
            if (sizeof($table_data) != 0)
            {
                foreach ($table_data as $data)
                {
                    if($password == $data->password)
                    {

                        $responsedata["firstname"] = $data->firstname;
                        $responsedata["lastname"] = $data->lastname;
                        $responsedata["email"] = $data->email;
                        $responsedata["userid"] = $data->userid;
                        $responsedata["displaypic"] = $data->displaypic; //THIS IS THE BASE64
                        $responsedata["ispersonaldetailsfilled"] = $data->ispersonaldetailsfilled;
                        $responsedata["isexpertisedetailsfilled"] = $data->isexpertisedetailsfilled;
                        $responsedata["isprofessionaldetailsfilled"] = $data->isprofessionaldetailsfilled;

                        $this->response(array("success"=>$responsedata), 200);
                        //$this->response($responsedata, 200);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->response(array("error"=>"Password not matched"), 200);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->response(array("error"=>"User not found"), 200);
            }



    }
    else
    {
        if($this->post('useremail') == "")
            {
                $this->response(array("error"=>"Useremail can't be null"),200);
            }
           if($this->post('password') == "")
            {
                $this->response(array("error"=>"Password can't be null"),200);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just missing a brace at the end. [Here's your corrected JSON](http://pastebin.com/YPkE4Gpr)

Always use tools to validate your json before posting a question. I personally like http://pro.jsonlint.com

Comment: I know it is missing a brace, But it is because I added the base64 string else without it the missing brace is there .. and it is an automatically generated JSON .. Let me update that code .. I am using Codeigniter to create a web service ...